# python: recover exception from try block if finally block raises exception

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, try-catch-finally

Say I have some code like this:

```
try:
    try:
        raise Exception("in the try")
    finally:
        raise Exception("in the finally")
except Exception, e:
    print "try block failed: %s" % (e,)
```

The output is:

```
try block failed: in the finally
```

From the point of that print statement, is there any way to access the exception raised in the try, or has it disappeared forever?

NOTE: I don't have a use case in mind; this is just curiosity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can't find any information about whether this has been backported and don't have a Py2 installation handy, but in Python 3, `e` has an attribute called `e.__context__`, so that:

```
try:
    try:
        raise Exception("in the try")
    finally:
        raise Exception("in the finally")
except Exception as e:
    print(repr(e.__context__))
```

gives:

```
Exception('in the try',)
```

According to [PEP 3314](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/), before `__context__` was added, information about the original exception was unavailable.

Comment: nice, but py3 only. anyways: +1.

Comment: ah, nice. so according to that PEP, the answer is, "you can't, in Py2, but you can in Py3". thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    try:
        raise Exception("in the try")
    except Exception, e:
        print "try block failed"
    finally:
        raise Exception("in the finally")
except Exception, e:
    print "finally block failed: %s" % (e,)
```

However, It would be a good idea to avoid having code that is likely to throw an exception in the `finally` block - usually you just use it to do cleanup etc. anyway.

Comment: That just swallows the `"in the try"` exception before it gets to the finally block.